# Change Breeze / Knockout Entity Property in code

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, single-page-application

Didn't see any other questions asking this and can't find the right resource, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction -

```
var archiveParent = function () {
    var msg = 'Archive parent "' + parent().name() + '" ?';
    var title = 'Confirm Archive';
    isArchiving(true);
    return app.showMessage(msg, title, ['Yes', 'No'])
        .then(confirmArchive);

    function confirmArchive(selectedOption) {
        if (selectedOption === 'Yes') {
            parent().archived() === true;
            save().then(success).fail(failed).fin(finish);

            function success() {
                router.navigateTo('#/parents');
            }

            function failed(error) {
                cancel();
                var errorMsg = 'Error: ' + error.message;
                logger.logError(
                    errorMsg, error, system.getModuleId(vm), true);
            }

            function finish() {
                return selectedOption;
            }
        }
        isArchiving(false);
    }

};

var save = function () {
    isSaving(true);
    return datacontext.saveChanges().fin(complete);

    function complete() {
        isSaving(false);
    }
};
```

I am changing a Knockout observable's property in the view model but KO does not appear to be firing the hasChanges() property on the EntityManager in the datacontext, therefore Breeze is not 'seeing' any changes to save.  I am sure I overlooking something stupid, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that can be this line of code:

```
parent().archived() === true;
```

What do you want to do with this line?

If you want to give the value true to the archived property, you have to do:

```
parent().archived(true);
```

Comment: That's correct ugh, tried it a hundred different ways before I posted this thanks for the help.